# Kann/soll ein Komma das rechte Außenfeld, das mit „oder“ beginnt und mit einem Nebensatz endet, einführen?

Tags: comma

Betrachten wir folgendes Beispiel:

> Für die automatische Erzeugung von modernen Liebeserklärungen können wir mit Corpora aus Chat- und Nachrichtenströmen arbeiten(,) oder mit Netzdatenströmen, die mit Zeitstempel versehen sind.

(Anmerkung: Der Beispielsatz wirkt konstruiert, so ist er auch. Den tatsächlichen Kontext kann ich aus Datenschutzgründen leider nicht hergeben.)

Soll ein Komma vor dem „oder“ stehen?  Nach meinem Verständnis ist „oder mit Netzdatenströmen, die mit Zeitstempel versehen sind“ eine Ausrahmung, aber diesen Begriff finde ich weder im [amtlichen Regelverzeichnis](http://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201) noch im [Dudenregelwerk](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma). Man könnte zwar einwenden, diese Wortgruppe wäre ein Nachtrag, aber das fände ich persönlich etwas gekünstelt.

Comment: Wenn beide Optionen gleichrangig sind, würde ich kein Komma setzen. Wenn die Netzdatenströme eine überraschende Alternative sein sollen, würde ich mich auf D107 berufen und eines setzen.

Answer (score 1):

Beides ist möglich – oder auch ein Gedankenstrich.

Grundsätzlich steht zwischen mit „oder“  verbundenen gleichrangigen Wortgruppen zwar KEIN Komma; die übergeordnete Regel lautet jedoch: Vor Zusätzen steht ein Komma. Der Schreibende entscheidet, ob der „Oder-Satz“ einfach der zweite Teil einer Reihe sein soll oder ein (besonders hervorzuhebender) Zusatz.

Erinnerte mich gleich an das Manifest der Kommunistischen Partei (1. Kapitel), 1848:

(…) einen Kampf, der jedesmal mit einer revolutionären Umgestaltung der ganzen Gesellschaft endete, oder mit dem gemeinsamen Untergang der kämpfenden Klassen.

Marx schiebt hier den Untergang lässig hinterher und hebt dies noch mit dem Komma hervor.

Answer (score 0):

Meiner Ansicht nach gehört da kein Komma hin.
Betrachten wir mal nur den Hauptsatz und stellen ihn in eine "übliche" Wortreihenfolge:

> Für die automatische Erzeugung von modernen Liebeserklärungen können wir mit Corpora aus Chat- und Nachrichtenströmen oder mit Netzdatenströmen arbeiten.

Hier ist es offensichtlich, dass da kein Komma hingehört.
Nun wird der Teil nach dem "oder" um einen erläuternden Relativsatz ergänzt:

> Für die automatische Erzeugung von modernen Liebeserklärungen können wir mit Corpora aus Chat- und Nachrichtenströmen oder mit Netzdatenströmen, die mit Zeitstempel versehen sind, arbeiten.

Immer noch ganz offensichtlich kein Komma.
Nun könnte der Leser allerdings irrtümlich annehmen, der Relativsatz bezöge sich auf beide Möglichkeiten statt nur auf die zweite. Außerdem klingt es (besonders beim Sprechen) eher unbeholfen, wenn nach dem Relativsatz nur noch ein einziges Wort - das Verb des Hauptsatzes - folgt. Aus diesen beiden Gründen wird das "arbeiten" hier vor das "oder" gezogen, ohne das sich meiner Ansicht nach die eigentliche Satzstruktur dadurch ändert.
Im Gegensatz zur englischen Sprache werden in der deutschen die Kommata nicht danach gesetzt, wo man beim Sprechen eine natürliche Pause machen würde.